# update_user_meta duplicates entry

Tags: array

I have a very simple code in my themes footer

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
 $user = wp_get_current_user();
 $aka2 = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_visited_blogs', true);
 $aka2[] = 'blog4';
 update_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_visited_blogs', $aka2);
} ?>
```

What it does is, gets meta value, inserts new entry and updates meta with new a array.

like if it contain something:

[0] => 'blog1',

[1] => 'blog2',

[2] => 'blog3'

and after function it should look like

[0] => 'blog1',

[1] => 'blog2',

[2] => 'blog3',

[3] => 'blog4'

but, what it does is, it inserts two values on execution even when it's empty

[0] => 'blog4',
[1] => 'blog4'

and on every next execution it inserts two values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the existing values instead you should check if existing values exist and concatenate the new values to existing values if it is exist as following

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
 $user = wp_get_current_user();
 $aka2 = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_visited_blogs',true);
  if($aka2)
 array_push ($aka2, 'blog4');
 else
 $aka2 = array('blog4');
  update_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_visited_blogs', $aka2);
}
```

Comment: I copy/pasted your code but it does the same, it inserts it twice

Comment: a:2:{i:0;s:5:"blog4";i:1;s:5:"blog4";}

that's from my database

Comment: Try deleting existing values using delete_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_visited_blogs');

Comment: $user = wp_get_current_user();

 $aka2 = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_visited_blogs',true);
 update_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_visited_blogs');
  if($aka2)
 array_push ($aka2, 'blog4');
 else
 $aka2 = array('blog4');
  update_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_visited_blogs', $aka2);


<p>I did it like this but no :( how this can be happening, I triple checked everything

Comment: retried it with delete_user_meta, sadly it does not work so ether

Comment: when I dump $aka2 in the end of my code it displays  array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "blog4" } but inserts two of them

Comment: You are using wrong code , use code as i have written. Do not use update_user_meta function twice.

Comment: and In my ff logs I have:
[13:46:22.021] POST http://mydomain.ge/index.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 535ms]

it posting to index.php, can it be the reason why it inserts twice?
I rewrote my code so first time, when there is no entry it enters blog4 and then if there is entry it enters 'blog42'. 

  if($aka2)
 array_push ($aka2, 'blog42');
 else
 $aka2 = array('blog4');


And with no entry after 1 refresh it inserted 
a:2:{i:0;s:5:"blog4";i:1;s:6:"blog42";}

Comment: In which file are you using this code?

Comment: yes I'm using it as you wrote it, it just first time before you edited your comment, then I rewrote it with delete_user_meta as you edited your comment

Comment: Have no idea, it was there as I remember myself doing this website. it has header with XMLHttpRequest

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8156/discussion-between-vinod-dalvi-and-mpa4hu)

Comment: yes the problem was this POST request which was requesting my site once again (jQuery.Post)
In any case I didn't needed this POST request (onload) so I changed the code and made the condition if the site is same, just return from function.
In any case I used your code to check if $aka contains anything, so I'll check this answer as a correct one as my question didn't cover POST request )